# How to remove array from Request class on laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5

**Data**

```
"image_comment" => array:4 [▶]
"album_photo" => array:3 [▶]
```

I cannot merge this 2 array since they're not equal in count. i want to remove the last array of image_comment. how can i do this? ive tried array_pop but it does work also laravel helpers for array. i prefer php for the solution for this instead javascript. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;

$collect = new Collection($request['image_comment']);
$array = $collect->toArray();
array_pop($array);
dd($array); //result: array[0 => 'first', => 1 => 'second', '2' => 'third']
```

We cannot use array helpers from laravel and array_pop directly on Request class. it will throw an error if you use this 2 options. **Cheers!**